# Mocha ES6 Relative Import

Tags: mocha.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to test one of my React components using Mocha and Enzyme. In my test file, I have an import statement like so:

```
import MyComponent from '../../../src/components/MyComponent';
```

In that component, I require a helper from a directory above:

```
import {COLORS}     from "../../helpers/THEME";
```

My problem is, that COLORS seems to be undefined. I've tried it with other files that are directories below and it doesn't work. It seems to be something with the import {...} from ... syntax.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

The export from THEME:

```
const COLORS = {
    white: "#ffffff",
    black: "#000000",
};

const BUTTON = {
    color: 'blue',
    width: 30
};

export default {
    COLORS,
    BUTTON,
};
```

Comment: `../../` is two directories above, could that be what's causing it?

Comment: How are you exporting things from `THEME`?

Comment: yeah, the path seems correct because webpack compiles it correctly. From THEME, I'm creating const objects and then 

export default {
    COLORS,
    BUTTONS
};

where COLORS and BUTTONS are key-value objects.

Comment: Another weird thing - if I import another file like import Logo from '../Logo'; it works, but using the 'import { ... } from ...' syntax seems to mess up.

Comment: Can you add the export from `THEME`?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson I added THEME into the original post.

Comment: Which version of Babel are you using?

Comment: "babel-core": "^5.8.22", "babel-loader": "^5.3.2", "babel-runtime": "^5.8.20", "babel-register": "^6.4.3"

Comment: Okay, what happens when you `console.log(require('../../helpers/THEME'));`? Do you see an object with the value `default`?

Comment: Yeah, the object is there with the key default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101018/discussion-between-happycry-and-henrik-andersson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Babel 6 then your `export default` will actually export an object with the key `default` set to your both objects.

```
export default { COLORS, BUTTONS };

//> { default: { COLORS: { hex: '#fff' }, BUTTONS: {} } };
```

This is the correct way of doing exports and Babel 5.x was doing it "wrong" and not according to spec.

In order to be able to use your object with `export default` you'd go with the full ES6 way and do

```
import theme from './THEME';
console.log(theme.COLORS);
//> { hex: '#fff' }
```

There's [A good read here](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0) which explains this is detail.